# Print the elements of the matrix with each row in a new line and elements of each row are separated by a space

Tags: python, matrix, input, split

> You are provided with the number of rows (R) and columns (C). Your task is to generate the matrix having R rows and C columns such that all the numbers are in increasing order starting from 1 in row wise manner.
>
> Input Format:
>   The first line contain two numbers R and C separated by a space.
>
> Output Format:
>   Print the elements of the matrix with each row in a new line and elements of each row are separated by a space.
>
> NOTE: There should not be any space after the last element of each row and no new line after the last row.
>
> Example:
>
> Input:

```
3 3
```

> Output:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

> I have tried the following code. It runs on the online compiler. But shows an error in some compilers , \n in the output. I want to remove this error

```
x=[]
a=[int(n) for n in input().split()]
#print(*a)

for i in range(a[0]):
    x.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))

for i in range(a[0]):
    for j in range(a[1]): 
        print(x[i][j], end = " ")
    print()
```

Desired output on new lines

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Actual output

```
1 2 3\n
4 5 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will take input in the form of line containing two numbers R and C separated by a space.

It will print the matrix with values separated by space:

```
R, C = map(int, input().split())

print('\n'.join(' '.join(str(C*row + col) for col in range(1, C+1)) for row in range(R)), end='')
```

Prints (in case of input `3 3`):

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Note: There isn't newline after the last line.

Comment: This is prettier than the original code, but technically does not create a matrix - it just prints the values that such a matrix would have. ;-)

Comment: True, should be: `print('\n'.join(' '.join(str(C*row + col) for col in range(1, C+1)) for row in range(R)), end='')`

Comment: @Amdoc Try now, I made minor correction. Thanks Skymon

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
for i in range(a[0]):
  for j in range(a[1]): 
    if (j == a[1]-1):
      print(x[i][j])
    else:
      print(x[i][j], end = " ")
```

You could also simplify your code a little bit to:

```
a=[int(n) for n in input().split()] # e.g. a = [2,4]

matrix = [[i*a[1]+j+1 for j in range(a[1])] for i in range(a[0])]
for m in matrix:
    print(*m)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r,c = input("Enter the number of Row and Column : ").split()
r=int(r)
c=int(c)
matrix=[]
count=0

for i in range(r*c):
    matrix.append(i+1)

for i in matrix:
    count+=1
    if(count==r):
        print(i)
        print("\n")
        count=0
    else:
        print(i,end=" ")
```